# Login Via Twitter

Tags: objective-c, twitter, parse-platform

It has been almost a month and I couldn't figure this out.

I am developing a social network application and I want the users to be able to log in via their **Twitter** and Facebook account Like the screenshot below:

[image: LoginVia Facebook and twitter]

The **Facebook** is done, and I am stock with the twitter, Note that these pictures are actually set as a buttons.

What I want exactly is:

The user can be able to login (sign up) on the application using their Twitter and I will retrieve the basic information from Twitter API "Name,Username,Profile picture" in my application and store them in my database.

**Note:** I am using Parse and I already have a table call user.
**Please help me** :'(

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't tried anything with Twitter yet.

If this were my code, I'd probably use the Twitter API to login, [which they introduce you to here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios).

Or you can use one of the [handy Objective-C libraries they've listed here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries)

Comment: Thats not correct actually I've tried few codes but let me tell you, some of the codes are old for iOS 6 and below, and the other codes don't work with parse. and by the way I am not looking for integration cause I already did it, I need just the login and retrieving information parts thats all :)

Comment: and the links you posted trust me I've been throw them all